# My Win32 C++ 'Hello World program' won't compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So my go to language is C#, so I decided to learn C++. I made a hello world program with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>    // include the standard input/output header file

void main(void)    // our program starts here
{
printf("Hello World!");    // print "Hello World!" into the console
return;    // return void to windows
}
```

But I then get this error when I compile (I am using Visual Studio 2015)

```
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Render Engine   c:\users\kamaldeep rai\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Render Engine\Debug\Render Engine.exe  

Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) Render Engine   c:\Users\kamaldeep rai\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Render Engine\Render Engine\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_winmain.obj)
```

Comment: You picked the wrong type of project for a win32 console application.

Comment: I'm learning DirectX programming so I have to use a regular Win32 project

Comment: @ArjanSingh in a Win32 project there is no `main`, but `WinMain`, and there also is no `printf`.

Comment: The code you wrote was for a win32 console application.

Comment: @ArjanSingh If you're learning C++ using tutorials, books, etc.  then the code you see in those tutorials are almost always going to fit the "Console Application" project type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Paul's answer, here is how you can change the configuration so that linker would look for `main`:

1. Open Project Properties
2. Goto Linker
3. System -> Subsystem
4. Change it to **Console**

Also, your `main` prototype is not compliant with C++, it should return `int`

Answer (score 4):

This error:

> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16

is caused by not choosing the correct project type when building your application.  Since you're using Visual Studio, you want to have a `Win32 Console Application` project.

Instead, you chose a project that has `WinMain` as the entry point instead of the traditional `main` entry point.